# Question marks in string due to character encoding in Request.Form

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a textarea where I type some unicode characters which become question marks by the time the string reaches the server.
On the input I typed the following:

> Don’t “quote” me on that.

On the server I checked `Request.Form["fieldID"]` in `Page_Load()` and I saw:

> "Don�t �quote� me on that."

I checked my web.config file and it says `<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" />`. Anything else I should check to ensure UTF-8 is enabled?

Comment: When you say that you checked on the server side do you mean that you used the debugger and got "Don�t �quote� me on that." in the watch window?  Could you please copy and paste the content of the string into something like MS Word and set the font to, say, Arial?  I just want to rule out the possibility that something funny is happening with your fonts in Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes I used the debugger. I know it is not the fonts because converting the character to an int shows up as 65533. [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5798110/266535) is related but doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: OK. Let's try something else then.  Have you used Fiddler to see what actually reaches your server? http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/ if you haven't got it already.

Comment: This is odd. It looks like the question marks are in the request to the server. I clicked TextView and WebForms and both say `Don�t �quote� me on that.` but the question marks appear as boxes.

Comment: As they do in my browser when I look at your question, which is why my first thought was about fonts.  Let me see what happens in one of my web apps when I feed it the same input...

Comment: Oh I think I figured out the problem. It only happens when a "feature" is turned on in the WebApp. This looks like @Pheonixblade9 might be right in that the text is being encoded twice.

Comment: In my test, the string is sent to the server (using POST) as it should be:&ApplNotes=Don%E2%80%99t+%E2%80%9Cquote%E2%80%9D+me+on+that.  Is that what you are getting also? (Use the Raw view.  The posted data are on the bottom line and are URL encoded.)

Comment: Great if you have figured it out.  Just post a full answer, as I am curious :-)

Comment: Thanks @MiltosKokkonidis, I ended up answering my own question but your comments were really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once I again I solve my own problem. It is quite simple. The short answer is add the following before sending any response back to the client:

```
Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8";
```

The long answer is that a "feature" called Cache Mode circumvented all other response data by writing a UTF-8 encoded file that is really just a cached response. Adding that line before it write the file solved my problem.

```
if (cacheModeEnabled) {
    Response.ContentType = "text/html; charset=utf-8"; // WriteFile doesn't know the file encoding
    Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath("CacheForm.aspx"), true);
    Response.End();
} else {
  // perform normal response here
}
```

Thanks for all the answers and comments. They definitely helped me solve this issue. Most notably, [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) let me see what the heck is really in the request and response.

Answer (score 0):

Question marks like that generally show up when UTF-8 nulls are passed.

You need to [HTML encode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991970/html-encoding-with-asp-net) your strings.

Comment: But this is coming straight from the client's request, not from the server. Can you provide an example?

Comment: So you receive a request with these invalid characters?  You control the webpage these data fields are on, correct?

Comment: I don't know what else to post. That's why my question is asking where to look next. Something is happening before Page_Load.

Comment: I think you might be right in that the text is being encoded twice.

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding of the `Page` where the `form` is, and/or the `accept-charset` of the `form`.

I can replicate what you are seeing with `ISO-8859-1` - e.g.

```
<form action="foo" method="post" accept-charset="ISO-8859-1">
   ....
</form>
```

**In VS watch window**:

---

Inspecting `Request.Form` (before accessing the key itself):

```
message=Don%ufffdt+%ufffdquote%ufffd+me+on+that.
```

Inspecting `Request.Form["message"]` - accessing the collection keys which means ASP.Net has already *automatically urldecoded*:

```
"Don�t �quote� me on that."
```

It *seems* something is overriding your web.config settings on that specific page (?)

Hth...